# Asp.net local copy of db for tests (.mdf ?)

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

Without a backstory:

1. I have a database on a server, however I got a script which creates this DB
2. I executed this script in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I can use it now on my computer as local db.
3. I would like to test my `StorageContext` which on default uses `StorageContext` in `web.config`

   ```
   public StorageContext(string name = "name=StorageContext") : base(name) { }
   ```

I thought that maybe making a local copy of that database as a `*.mdf` file. Then add connection string and when making `StorageContext` just use that `TestDatabase` as param.

However it I got this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Type initializer ... 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig'

Comment: What does your config looks like for connection string .?

Comment: for mdf files the connection string format is different . can you please try ths.

Comment: <add name="StorageContext"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                       database=TestDatabase;
                       AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|nameofmdffile.mdf;
                       User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 1):

I think if you remove the attached database file name and use something like this, your problem will be solved.

The connection string can look like this:

```
<add name="StorageContext" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
Integrated Security=SSPI; 
database=TestDatabase;   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
id=" "  password=" " >
```